# How to go to the first and last line using keyshort with IDEA on macbook pro?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I can't find the keyshort to go to the first line(top) or last line(bottom) inside the IDEA on macbook pro with the built-in keyboard.

What's is that?

Comment: You can look it up using Cmd + Shift + A and typing "move caret to page" + either "top" or "bottom". The shortcuts are displayed to the right.

Answer (score 0):

For IntelliJ on Mac OS X:

- <kbd>fn⌘ ←</kbd> moves the cursor to the start of the editor window
- <kbd>fn⌘ →</kbd> moves the cursor to the end of the editor window